# Como borrar los usuarios y passwords guardados en SQL Server

Tags: sql

tengo un duda con respecto al eliminar el historial de logeo de inicio de sesión en SQLServer.
NO quiero eliminar el usuario de inicio de sesión, sino el historial cuando uno ingresa.
Cómo puedo resolverlo?
Muchas gracias de antemano!

Saludos,

Answer (score 0):

Encontré como puedo resolverlo en este [link](https://programmerclick.com/article/14232354386/):

> La versión 2014 del registro de conexión se guarda en el siguiente archivo.
>
> C: \ Users \ {Nombre de usuario} \ AppData \ Roaming \ Microsoft \ SQL Server Management Studio \ 12.0 \ sqlstudio.bin
>
> Apague los SSMS y luego elimine el archivo SQLStudio.bin. Cuando se abra SSMS nuevamente, todos los registros de conexión se vaciarán.
>
> Tenga en cuenta que la necesidad de desactivar nuevamente, porque los SSMS se escriben una vez, este archivo de registro está escrito.

Siguiendo esos pasos pude resolver mi duda.